# Galasoft MVVM light windows 8 ResourceMap not found

Tags: mvvm

I am developing Windows 8 Metro app and getting "ResourceMap not found" exception when calling RaisePropertyChanged("PropertyName"). Can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps: the "ResourceMap not found" exception is thrown when you try to access a resource (eg. string) in a resource (.resw) file, and the given key cannot be found there.